# Update django database automatically with schedule

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-models

I am working on a Django project to track my daily tasks.
I hope my database can automatically create a new record as "unfinished" at midnight each day. How can I implement this feature in Django + React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2 Options** came to my mind:

**1-** Use `management command` and `cron`:

Read about `management command` in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands :

```
python manage.py YOUR_COMMAND
```

Then use `cron` in linux for setting scheduled task

**2- Use celery**

Read docs for using: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html